# Complementary slackness conditions (Kuhn-Tucker)

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

Consider the problem of maximising a smooth function subject to the inequality constraint that $g(x) \leq b$. The complementary slackness condition says that

$$ \lambda[g(x) - b] = 0$$

It is often pointed out that, if the constraint is slack at the optimum (i.e. $g(x^*) < b$), then this condition tells us that the multiplier $\lambda = 0$. I agree with this. However, it has also been said that, if the constraint 'binds' (which implies that $g(x^*) - b = 0$), we must have $\lambda > 0$. Is this true? As a logical matter, it is not immediately implied by the complimentary slackness condition: we could have both $g(x^*) - b = 0$ and also $\lambda = 0$.

**Edit:** it has been demonstrated [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248314/zero-lambda-zero-constraint-in-the-complementary-slackness-condition-of-the-kuh) why we can have both $\lambda = 0$ and $g(x^*) - b = 0$ (thanks to @markleeds for the pointer). I am wondering, however, whether we can have $\lambda = 0$ while the constraint also *binds* (i.e. makes a difference to the solution -- note that this is subtly different from the constraint holding with equality). I suspect that the answer is 'no' given that $\lambda$ reflects the effect of slightly relaxing the constraint on the objective function. However, I would appreciate confirmation of this.

Comment: Hi: I don't't have time to try to understand it but I think the last answer at the link below may be helpful. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248314/zero-lambda-zero-constraint-in-the-complementary-slackness-condition-of-the-kuh

Comment: Thanks I think that answers it!

Comment: Somewhat, at least: my feeling is that if the constraints binds (i.e. makes a difference to the solution), we must have $\lambda > 0$, even though the fact that the constraint holds with equality ($g(x^*) = 0$) does not imply that $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to have

$$g(x^*) = b\; {\rm and}\; \lambda^* = 0$$.

When the multiplier is zero and the constraint is equal to zero, then

a) The constraint does not really "bind"

b) That's why the multiplier is zero.

**What does it mean "the constraint does not really bind"?**

It means that the solution $x^*$, that makes $g(x^*) = b$, would be chosen *even if the constraint was not imposed*. In that sense, the constraint is not really *binding*, because it does not really forbid us to go where we wanted to be, because we are already there.

Consider the simple example

$$\max_x \{-ax^2 + bx\},\qquad s.t. \;x \geq \frac{b}{2a} $$

The Lagrangean is

$$\Lambda = -ax^2 + bx + \lambda \left(x -\frac{b}{2a}\right)$$

and the f.o.c is

$$x = \frac{b+\lambda}{2a}$$.

Try cases:

a) $\lambda^* = 0$ leads to $x^* = \frac{b}{2a}$, which is the unconstrained f.o.c. also.

b) $\lambda^* > 0$ the f.o.c. initially indicates that $x^* > b/2a$. But then the constraint is not binding and we should have $\lambda^* =0$ : contradiction.

So we see that in this case the solution is

$$x^* = \frac{b}{2a},\;\;\; \lambda^* = 0.$$

So the constraint *appears* to be binding, but it really is not.

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is correct. Say you know that $Z=X\cdot Y=0$ You don't know if $X=0$ or $Y=0$ or both are zero. Even if you know that $X=0$ you have no idea if $Y=0$, $Y<0$ , or $Y>0$.

Consider the potentially satiated utility function:
$$ \max_{X,Y} U(X,Y) = min(X+Y, 5)$$
$$ S.T. \:p_x X + p_y Y + p_z Z\leq M$$
Assume, for simplicity, that $p_x = p_y = p_z =1$. In lagrangian form this is:
$$ \max_{X,Y} U(X,Y) = min(X+Y, 5) - \lambda (X+Y+Z-M) $$ 
Z is the free disposal good, in that it uses up extra money but provides no utility. If $M>5$ then the budget constraint binds. Under this condition, $\lambda$ is the shadow value of more income, and is also zero.

Or, if that utility function doesn't suit you, consider:
$$ \max_{X,Y} U(X,Y) = -(X+Y-5)^2 - \lambda (X+Y+Z-M) $$
If $X+Y>5$ then the household wants to use free disposal and set $X+Y=5$. The budget constraint doesn't bind and the MU of income is zero:
$MU_{X+Y+Z=5}=-2(X+Y-5)=0$.

Comment: Right, but is the following true: if the constraint binds (i.e. makes a difference to the solution), then we must have $\lambda > 0$? I suspect that the answer is 'yes'

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The second statement is logically incorrect. To make the point, let me write for convenience sake $\tilde{g}(x):=g(x) - b$. Then by the complementary slackness condition, we have

$$\lambda \cdot \tilde{g}(x) = 0 $$

which comes from the Kuhn-Tucker optimality conditions $\tilde{g}(x) \le 0$ (primal feasibility of the solution) and $\lambda \ge 0$ (dual feasibility of the solution). By these constraints, we realize that both can hold as equalities, but not as inequalities. However, if $\lambda > 0$, then $\tilde{g}(x) =0$. This statement is equivalent to the contra-positive statement that if $\tilde{g}(x) <0$, then $\lambda = 0$. We observe that we can infer from an inequality constraint that the other constraint must hold by equality. However, we cannot infer that if a constraint holds by equality, then the other must be an inequality. This is a fallacy.

Comment: I definitely believe that both of you are correct but I'm pretty sure that I also remember reading what a@freelunch pointed out. how could so many texts have this incorrect statement ?

Comment: @markleeds Unfortunately, wrong logic is a great issue in the literature. In this respect, the following link https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00409 might be of interest to clarify the problem.

Comment: thanks. I'll check it out.